# Phonegap send email (PHP and jQuery) : no variable POST

Tags: php, jquery, cordova, email

I have searched in other posts or tutorials but unfortunately nothing works for me...

I use PhoneGap for a little application with a form. My simplified idea is : When a visitor write his email in the input and click on "Send", it send me an email with his email. BUT, for now, my variable `$_POST['email']` is empty when I send the form...

So this is my form:

```
<form action="http://my-domain-name/app_mail.php"  method="POST">
    <div id="coord">
        <h3>Vos coordonnées</h3>
        <div class="group">
            <input id="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required">
        </div>
        <div class="group">
            <input id="envoyer" value="Envoyer" type="submit">
        </div>                
    </div>
</form>
```

I use this jQuery code:

```
$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.post({
        // My variables
        url: 'http://my-domain-name/app_mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val()
        }

    // Fonction HTML
    }, function(html) {
        var response = html;
        if(response == "success") {
            alert("Email envoyé avec succès !");
        } else {
            alert("Votre email n'a pas pu être envoyé...");
            return false;
        }
    });

$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

I have found this code on internet and I have adapt it for my needs... So if I'm not wrong, this code allow cross domain for this function, use variables url, type and data and finally write a message if the PHP works or not.

And finally, my PHP:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$header = "From: ".$email;
$message = $email;

// Validation
if($email == "") {
    echo "Erreur";
    echo "<br>Email :".$email;
} else {
    mail("my-email@my-domain.fr", "Message reçu depuis l'application", $message, $header);
    echo "Succès";
}
```

When I try to send the form, I have this answer:

"Erreur
Email :"

on a new page... I don't have any errors in console or in PHP if I add `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` in my PHP file....

So I think my variable isn't transmitted but I don't know why...

Comment: if you are on chrome, open network inspector and then select preserve log option and then click btn and then firstly check if ajax request is going or not then check if its going ,click on request and go to params tab to see if email is going or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It's working with the esskay's solution and yes, I can see my file when I send the form! Thanks for this trick :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your statement in the html form to the following syntax

```
<input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required">
```

I have added the name tag using which 'S_POST" works .

you can edit this following one to your own page :

```
 <?php
 $email=$_POST['mail'];
 $header = "From: ".$email;
 $message = $email;

include '__lib__/class.phpmailer.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();                                     
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';

$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";  
     $mail->Port = 465;

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     // turn on SMTP authentication
//you must use an existing email address 
$mail->Username = 'email address-anything yahoo or google';  // SMTP username

$mail->Password = 'password for the email '; // SMTP password

$mail->From = 'xyz@yahoo.co.in';


$mail->FromName ='HelpQueires';

$mail->AddAddress($email);               



$mail->WordWrap = 50;                              

$mail->IsHTML(true);                              
$mail->Subject = 'Student Help Queries';

$mail->Body  = "hello";
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

if(!$mail->Send())
{
    echo "<h1>Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo.'</h1>';

}
else
    echo "<h1>Mail Send Successfully</h1>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! It's "working". I mean, I have the success message BUT I don't receive any emails... And this PHP code works on my other website... so do you know if I have to add something else...? I'm a bit lost....

Comment: try including the phpmailer.php  class using include statement

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I have added `require_once('phpmailer.php');` in my PHP file but it still doesn't works (I have the same result)... (of course I have also added the file on my FTP server).

Comment: did u download the file phpmailer ?

Comment: Sure! I have download this file: [link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php)

Comment: i dont where u went wrong ...did u try "include"  instead of require ?

Comment: It's working! :D I will post my code later, I don't have a lot of time for now, but thanks alot for your precious help!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but this is my final code. Hope it will help someone!

So, the HTML (thanks to esskay, it's not working without the `name` tag):

```
<form action="http://your-domain/app_mail.php" method="POST">
    <div class="group">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <input id="envoyer" value="Send" type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Then, this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.ajax({
        // Variables
        url: 'http://your-domain/app_mail.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            email: $('#email').val()
        }
    // Fonction HTML
    }, function(html) {
        var response = html;
        // PHP done and email sent
        if(response == "success") {
            alert("Email sent !");
        } else {
            alert("Email can't been sent...");
            return false;
        }
    });
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

So here, you have to write the URL of your PHP file (the PHP code is below), the type (POST or GET) and your data. The `function(html)` is not necessary. Finally, the  following function allows Cross Domaine Page for the ajax:

```
$(document).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    // Ajax function
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
});
```

PHP code:

```
require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

// Variables
$email = $_POST['email'];
$to = "your@email.fr";
$sujet = "Your subject";
$message = "Message from".$email."\r\n\r\n";

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // or 'ssl' depending of your configuration
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // host for gmail
$mail->Port = 465; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->Username = $to;
$mail->Password = "your-password";
$mail->SetFrom($email);
$mail->Subject = $sujet;
$mail->Body = $message;
$mail->AddAddress($to);

if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Sent !";
}
```

[You have to download PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Be careful: **all files from PHPMailer have to be in the same folder**. Also, this code works for me but if you add `$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP` , it not working anymore... Still don't know why... But anyways, hope this code will work for you! Thanks again esskay for your precious help!